# My CSS columns wider than the webpage but are supposed to be proportional

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have 2 css columns on my page: the left one is 75%, and the right is 25%. However, for some reason the right column is sticking out slightly, making it wider than the page (pictured on bottom). How I make both columns together the same width as the logo on top?

This is my base html:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-175481126-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-175481126-1');
</script>

<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
 li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
   color: white;
   text-decoration:none;
 }

/* for buttons*/
.paging {
background-color: #333;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.register {
  float: right;
}

.paging {
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

/* title */

.title {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  Color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* descriptions */

.description {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* embedd url */
.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0;
    margin-left: auto;   /* Automatic margin from left */ 
    margin-right: auto; /* Automatic margin from right */
}
.iframe-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* make columns */

.ads {
  float: right;
  background-color: #c1c4c9;
  width: 25%;
}

.videos {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.image {
/*  padding-right: 3%;*/
/*  padding-left: 3%;*/
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.banner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* header */
.header {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<html>

{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>

<div class="header">
  <a href="/">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5Rqps7F/logo-black.png" alt="Computer Man">
</a>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="all"><a href="/">All videos</a></li>
  <li class="stam"><a href="/stam">Stam videos</a></li>
  <li class="music"><a href="/music">Music videos</a></li>
  <li class="news"><a href="/news">News videos</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="register"><a href="/register">Login/Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="banner">
    <text align="center">We are still developing our site, so we may not be able to update videos as often as we want</text>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the page html:

```
{% include 'base.html' %}
<style>
    .{{ category }} {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="videos">
    {% autoescape off %}
            <h1 class="title"> {{ video_.title }} </h1>
            {% ifnotequal video_.tag 'none' %}
                <small align = left> {{ video_.tag }} </small>
            {% endifnotequal %}
            <div class="iframe-container"><p align="center"> {{ video_.url }}</p></div>
            <div class="description"> {{ video_.description }} </div>
            <hr/>

{% endautoescape %}
    </div>

    <div class="ads">
        {% for ad in ad_item %}
            {% ifequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
                <img class="image" src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifnotequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
                <a href="{{ ad.redirect }}"><img class="image" src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img></a>
            {% endifnotequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: You can see here]

You can also see on my site, tachlis.herokuapp.com (that's where the problem is).

Comment: This is due to the rules margin-right: -15px and margin-left: -15px in the .row class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're describing in your question is due to elements overflowing the body width. Now, knowing this, it's always an annoyance trying to actually narrow down which element is causing this.

One way to figure it out is to run this script in the console:

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

I took the liberty to do that on your site, and the culprit is this block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="videos>
        .....
    </div>
    <div class="ads">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

A very quick fix would be to simply add `overflow-x: hidden` to the body element.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You could also go through your row block and see what specifically is causing the overflow to happen.

The ideal solution would be to add `*{ box-sizing: border-box; }`, define a width of 100% for your row element, remove the margins from your row element.

Example CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* you can just remove these margins all together. Just wanted to emphasize that there should be no margin left or right, to avoid overflow */
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.ads {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-color: #c1c4c9;
    width: 25%;
}

.videos {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a <div> called 'body', which should I put it in? Thanks!

Comment: The body element is a html tag. You can target html tags in CSS directly, i.e. `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`. But I have a more ideal solution for you if you give me a second.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @KovyJacob see recent edits. The ideal solution should fix your problem in an optimal manner. The main reason why the row block is overflowing the body, is because it had margins and an undefined width.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem @KovyJacob Feel free to mark the answer as correct and leave an upvote if you please.

Comment: That worked, but now its doing this: https://ibb.co/YQPPvtR. Instead, now the top (with the logo) is a bit wider. How do I correct that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230671/discussion-between-martin-and-kovy-jacob).

Answer (score 0):

Using flex on the container and float on the children will not work. Erase the floats, remove `flex-wrap` from the container, add `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements and - if you want strict widths - use `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shrink: 0` on the child elements (= your "columns").

Comment: which <div> would I put each one in? I'm not sure I totally understand. Thanks!

Comment: You already have a flex-container: `.row`. It has two children - your "colummns", currently floated. Those are the elements I am talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry @Johannes, I'm not so advanced. Would you by any chance be able to change up those 2 divs for me  and paste it in a comment? Thanks!

Comment: `* {box-sizing: border-box; } .row { display: flex; } .videos, .ads {  flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; } .videos {width: 75%; } .ads {width: 25%; }`. There is also some other stuff to be fixed, but this does the basic functionality of creating two "columns" inside your `.row` container